# combine 2 variable data frame with same number of rows to 1 single data frame in google script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I have 2 data frames.

1st Data frame after few data manipulations looks like this

```html
Date
1/2/2019
1/3/2019
1/4/2019
1/5/2019
1/6/2019
1/7/2019
1/8/2019
1/9/2019
```

The 2nd Data Frame is a range obtained from google sheet which looks like this

```html
DATA UCL
0.005 0.015
0.005 0.015
0.005 0.015
0.005 0.015
0.005 0.015
0.005 0.015
0.005 0.015
0.005 0.015
```

How do i combine these 2 variables to form a single data frame which can be passed.

to look like this

```html
Date DATA UCL
1/2/2019 0.005 0.015
1/3/2019 0.005 0.015
1/4/2019 0.005 0.015
1/5/2019 0.005 0.015
1/6/2019 0.005 0.015
1/7/2019 0.005 0.015
1/8/2019 0.005 0.015
1/9/2019 0.005 0.015
```

This is the current code

```js
    var Bvals = sheet.getRange("B12:B").getValues(); 

    var Blast = Bvals.filter(String).length; 

    var daterange = sheet.getRange(firstrow, 1, Blast, 1); 

    var Dateconverted = Utilities.formatDate(daterange, "GMT", ""EEE MMM dd yyyy");  

    range = sheet.getRange(firstrow, 2, Blast, 3);  

    var datarange2 = range.getValues();
```

Dateconverted is the 1st data frame, datarange2 is the 2nd data frame with 2 columns. I wish to combine these 2 data frames as Var Data3 = {some code to combine these 2 data tables to create one data table}

Answer (score 0):

A range is basically a two-dimensional array that works like `valueOfCellInRange = range[rowIndex][columnIndex]`, so to "extend" each row to include values from two rows in different ranges, you should be able to do something like:

```
var newRangeValues = [];
for (var i = 0; i < dataRange1.length; i++){
  // Length of the outer array will be the number of rows to loop through
  //   (assumes the two source ranges have an equal number of rows)
  var combinedRow = dataRange1[i].concat(dataRange2[i]); 
  // dataRange1[i] will hold a one-item array like ["Date"]
  // dataRange2[i] will hold an array like ["DATA","UCL"]
  // concat() will merge them into one array

  newRangeValues.push(combinedRow);
}
myTargetRangeOnSheet.setValues(newRangeValues);
```

Note: I haven't tested this code in google sheets, but it should be pretty close to what you're trying to do. (And you can check out this [explanation of the concat method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) for arrays.)

Here it is in a code snippet just to show that it works in the broswer:

```js
const dataRange1 = [
  ["Date"],
  ["1/1/19"]
];
const dataRange2 = [
  ["DATA", "UCL"],
  ["DATA thing", "UCL thing"]
];
const newRangeValues = [];

for (let i = 0; i < dataRange1.length; i++){
  const combinedRow = dataRange1[i].concat(dataRange2[i]); 
  newRangeValues.push(combinedRow);
}
console.log(newRangeValues);
```

Comment: Great, changes made. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Hi,  may i know what does is the newRangeValues.push(combinedRow);
}
myTargetRangeOnSheet.setValues(newRangeValues); used for?.  does this var combinedRow= dataRange1[i].concat(dataRange2[i]);  give me a dataframe with the 2 data table combined to form one?

Comment: In google script (very similar to javascript), arrays have a `.push` method, which adds a new element to the array. In this case, we are adding `combindedRow` to the `newRangeValues` array. That is, we are adding a new row to the new "data table" (which is originally empty.)  If you already defined a variable called `myTargetRangeOnSheet` (like maybe `var myTargetRangeOnSheet = sheet.getRange("D12");`), then`myTargetRangeOnSheet.setValues(newRangeValues);` can place this new "data table" on the sheet. So, yes, I think "give me a dataframe with the 2 data table combined to form one?" is right.